# Android 4.2 How To Keep Phone And Tablet Updates Separate?

Tags: android, android-layout

High density phone devices now support tablet size and phone.  I have an app in the marketplace and I need to update the phone project to support 4.2, but its overriding the tablet version 4.2  They both have the same package name.  Thanks

Comment: You do not have two apps in the Play Store with the same package name.

Comment: They are already there.  What would you suggest now?

Comment: It is not possible to have two apps in the Play Store with the same package name. Hence, it is not possible that "they are already there".  It *is* possible to have multiple APK files for the same app, per Pheonixblade9's answer.

Comment: ok.  let me get the details on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If they have the same package name, you can't override them without [following the steps to create multiple APKs for different screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/screensize.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest you could add a declaration that you did not want to support the larger screen sizes.

```
              <supports-screens
                android:smallScreens="true"
                android:normalScreens="true"
                android:largeScreens="true"
                android:xlargeScreens="false"
                android:anyDensity="true"
              />
```

Comment: Some smaller tablets may use the largerScreen attribute though as some larger phones. You can push the version for the phone out and the tablets wont see it and vice versa.